# docker-java run container with -rm flag

Tags: java, docker, docker-java

I am using [docker-java](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java) to spawn new containers.
I want to remove the containers after they are finished.
Is there a way to achieve this with docker-java?

So I basically want something like

```
docker run --rm my-docker
```

with docker-java.

Comment: I am aware of the remove container function but I would prefer the to have this done automatically after the container stopped.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [the Docker HTTP API](https://docs.docker.com/engine/api/v1.40/#operation/ContainerCreate), the `docker run --rm` option translates to an `AutoRemove` option inside a `HostConfig` object.  The Java API mirrors this object layout.  The [`docker-java` wiki](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/wiki) doesn't have any good examples of using that object, but it's [in the Java API too](https://github.com/docker-java/docker-java/blob/master/docker-java-api/src/main/java/com/github/dockerjava/api/model/HostConfig.java).

```java
import com.github.dockerjava.api.command.CreateContainerResponse;
import com.github.dockerjava.api.model.HostConfig;

HostConfig hostConfig = HostConfig
  .newHostConfig()
  .withAutoRemove(true);             // Set the "remove" flag

CreateContainerResponse container = dockerClient
  .createContainerCommand("busybox")
  .withHostConfig(hostConfig)        // Add in the HostConfig object
  .exec();
```